Did Sol Regem know what he was doing?
On the one hand, Sol Regem was blind and being directed by an elf that

 was corrupted by Aaravos,

so it is at least possible that he did not know where he was. The latter also said that he had manipulated him.
On the other hand, one might expect Sol Regem to be able to tell the difference between the flight time to the sunfire elves' encampment—close enough that Karim brought his army there in less than a day—and Katolis—days or weeks away on foot. Once there, he also crashed into a stone castle several times, and possibly could tell the difference between that and strafing an army in an open field.
Furthermore, given that he blames humans for his injuries, and given also his frequently expressed complete disinterest in Karim's cause, he might be expected to be amenable to attacking Katolis instead of intervening in the sunfire elves' internal power struggle.
Did Sol Regem know that he was attacking the humans or not?
